# When will UDS sponsorship final list be announced?

Tags: community

UDS-O is being held at Budapest, Hungary and the sponsorships are open which closes on 28th of March.

My question is when will the final list be announced? Will there be more than one month period for people to apply for Visa?

e.g. I live in India and when we apply for `Schengen Visa` for the first time, it takes around 2 weeks for the visa interview(period depends on the rush). Then another week for interview and Visa to be stamped. AFAIK the application, interview and collection has to be done in person. This is all what I have heard.

So will Canonical give one month time minimum for people in Eastern part of the world or countries where Schengen countries have tougher rules for visa?

It would be great if they could finalize the names a bit faster and announce the list by first week of April.

I am hoping Jorge or Jono might come and answer this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "final list" that is published. People who submit for sponsorship get a private email.

We try to do this with as much lead time as possible, unfortunately this can be problematic for some countries with Visas that can take longer than others.

We are keen on turning around the sponsorship as fast as we can after the 29 March deadline. The email sent to folks will have details on getting Visa letters on company letterhead and all that sort of paperwork.